# describe-db-parameters with query

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

When I run `describe-db-parameters` I understand that I need to submit a `--db-parameter-group-name`
If I run: `aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name pgname --region us-east-2` it works as expected.
However.
I want to run it with a query like:

```
aws rds describe-db-parameters --query 'Parameters[?DBParameterGroupName == pgname].[*]' --region us-east-2
```

I get the following error:

> aws: error: the following arguments are required:
>   --db-parameter-group-name

Please can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?  My guess is that `DBParameterGroupName` is the wrong thing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`--db-parameter-group-name` is a required field. You must provide it.

Comment: I was hoping someone might suggest where I have gone wrong in the script.

Comment: You have gone wrong in the command because you did not provide the required `--db-parameter-group-name` parameter. It _must_ be provided.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I was looking for.  One of the devs in my office helped me out.  I needed to put the query after specifying the PG name.

aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name xxx \
--query 'Parameters[?starts_with(ParameterName,`myisam_max_sort_file_size`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`innodb_buffer_pool_instance`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`innodb_read_io_threads`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`innodb_write_io_threads`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`myisam_sort_buffer_size`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`bulk_insert_buffer_size`) ||starts_with(ParameterName,`key_buffer_size`)].[ParameterName,ParameterValue]' \
--region eu-central-1 --output table